# Multiple changes to SharePoint Document Library but I only want to send one email

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have a document library in SharePoint Online. The end user submits about 30 documents to add metadata and to be approved. One column of the metadata is used to group the documents together. If the documents are approved no email is necessary. If they are rejected the library curator selects all the documents in the group and through bulk editing fills in a multi-lined column marked Deficiency with the reason why of the rejection, then changes another column to Rejected to initiate the workflow.

This sends out as many emails as there are document in that grouping. Is there any way to send out just one email when the grouping set is rejected?

haven4444

Answer (score 0):

I think we can accomplish this by following these steps:

1. Create a Power Automate (MS Flow) with **For a selected file** trigger for the Document Library. This Power Automate (PA) can be run manually on a selected file from a Library View. (See the screenshot below)
2. Within the PA, retrieve the selected file's properties by using **Get file properties** action and using the ID passed to PA for the selected file.
3. The retrieved File's properties should include metadata for the **group** of files
4. Retrieve all files' properties (meta data) by using **Get files (properties only)** action and using **Filter Query** passing **group**. Please note that, this value can be passed as parameter during PA run time as well. In that case, step 2 is not required. Need to create an **Input** parameter in PA.
5. Once all properties are available in PA, construct email body as needed. To do so, additional steps such as **Apply to each** to process each file's property and Initialize and Set Variables are needed to construct the email body and recipients' list.
6. Once the email body is constructed with recipients' list determined (stored in variables), send a single email.

### Screenshot showing how to run PA manually

[image]

### Example of PA

Need to add additional steps as needed
[image]

### Detail 1

[image]